# Pandas, most secure way to drop duplicates based on two labels, keeping the row with highest third label score

Tags: python, pandas

Say that my dataframe looks like this

```
score label1 label2
.9923   a      b
.3924   a      b
.2923   a      c
```

I want to remove all duplicates based on label1 and label2, keeping the highest value from score.

So result would look like

```
score label1 label2
.9923   a      b
.2923   a      c
```

I came up with

```
df.sort_values(by=['Score'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['label1', 'label2'], keep='first')
```

It's meant to organize the data by score, and then drop duplicates, keeping the first that comes up in the dataframe.

It seems to work, though I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it; will this work for all edge cases?

Comment: Your solution does reliably solve your question.

Comment: Which version of python are you using in this?

Comment: I am using python 3.6

Comment: yes it answers it exactly